# Issue when dragging Text in Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm currently working on a photo editor and I'm at the part of where your ability to add text to the image and drag it around, Well when you drag the text around it shows exactly where you had moved it to [What It looks like when you move the text around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXkIc.png)

Any Ideas on what Is causing this? Or any way of fixing it? I've played with the code for a while now and haven't been able to fix this issue. Thank You In Advance! :)

HTML:

```
<input id="theText" type="text">
<button id="submit">Draw text on canvas</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>


<div id="image_div">
<h1> Choose an Image to Upload </h1>
<input type='file' name='img' id='uploadimage' />

</div>
```

Image upload Script :

```
<script>
//Uploads Image from Input to Cavans :p //
function draw(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
        img = new Image(),
        f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
        url = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
        src = url.createObjectURL(f);

    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        url.revokeObjectURL(src);
    }
}

document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", draw, false)

</script>
```

Script that makes the Text Move Able:

```
<script>

// canvas related variables
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// variables used to get mouse position on the canvas
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();

// variables to save last mouse position
// used to see how far the user dragged the mouse
// and then move the text by that distance
var startX;
var startY;

// an array to hold text objects
var texts = [];

// this var will hold the index of the hit-selected text
var selectedText = -1;

// clear the canvas & redraw all texts                                                ====
function draw() {
    ctx.rect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
        var text = texts[i];
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fillText(text.text, text.x, text.y);



    }
}

// test if x,y is inside the bounding box of texts[textIndex]
function textHittest(x, y, textIndex) {
    var text = texts[textIndex];
    return (x >= text.x && x <= text.x + text.width && y >= text.y - text.height && y <= text.y);
}

// handle mousedown events
// iterate through texts[] and see if the user
// mousedown'ed on one of them
// If yes, set the selectedText to the index of that text
function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    // Put your mousedown stuff here
    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
        if (textHittest(startX, startY, i)) {
            selectedText = i;
        }
    }
}

// done dragging
function handleMouseUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    selectedText = -1;
}

// also done dragging
function handleMouseOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    selectedText = -1;
}

// handle mousemove events
// calc how far the mouse has been dragged since
// the last mousemove event and move the selected text
// by that distance
function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (selectedText < 0) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // Put your mousemove stuff here
    var dx = mouseX - startX;
    var dy = mouseY - startY;
    startX = mouseX;
    startY = mouseY;

    var text = texts[selectedText];
    text.x += dx;
    text.y += dy;
    draw();
}

// listen for mouse events
$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});

$("#submit").click(function () {

    // calc the y coordinate for this text on the canvas
    var y = texts.length * 20 + 20;

    // get the text from the input element
    var text = {
        text: $("#theText").val(),
        x: 20,
        y: y
    };

    // calc the size of this text for hit-testing purposes
    ctx.font = "16px verdana";
    text.width = ctx.measureText(text.text).width;
    text.height = 16;

    // put this new text in the texts array
    texts.push(text);

    // redraw everything
    draw();

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Save the reference of the image after it is loaded.
2. During mouse move, clear the canvas and add the image again using
   the reference saved in step (1) and then call the `draw()` method
   again.

Relevant code snippets

```
var drawnImage;
function drawImage(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
        img = new Image(),
        f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
        url = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
        src = url.createObjectURL(f);
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function () {
        drawnImage = img;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        url.revokeObjectURL(src);
    }
}
document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", drawImage, false);

function redraw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(drawnImage,0,0);
    draw();
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (selectedText < 0) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // Put your mousemove stuff here
    var dx = mouseX - startX;
    var dy = mouseY - startY;
    startX = mouseX;
    startY = mouseY;
    var text = texts[selectedText];
    text.x += dx;
    text.y += dy;
    redraw();
}
```

Sample fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rbkdLbcm/1/  (Image upload will not work)

Comment: So that Doesn't quite work that is why I didn't have ctx.clearRect and instead had ctx.rect because it then hides the image when you move the text around in the canvas.

Comment: Oh.. I tried without uploading image..let me check if there is another way

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out but have no clue. I've researched ways to make text move able in a canvas to see if I could find another way around this but have had no luck with it.

Comment: Pls check updated answer. However you will be better off using some library like fabric.js if you want to do element level changes in canvas too much..

Comment: It Worked! Sweet Thank You! I'll Look into fabric.js